# What is the fastest way to slice a scipy.sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I normally use

```
matrix[:, i:]
```

It seems not work as fast as I expected.

Comment: mind benchmarking it for us? perhaps even use `timeit`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To obtain a sparse matrix as output the fastest way to do row slicing is to have a `csr` type, and for columns slicing `csc`, [as detailed here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix). In both cases you just have to do what you are currently doing:

```
matrix[l1:l2, c1:c2]
```

If you want a `ndarray` as output it might be faster to perform the slicing directly in the `ndarray` object, which you can obtain from the sparse matrix using the `.A` attribute or the `.toarray()` method:

```
matrix.A[l1:l2, c1:c2]
```

or:

```
matrix.toarray()[l1:l2, c1:c2]
```

As mentioned in the comment below, converting the sparse array to a dense array might lead to memory errors if the array is big enough.

Comment: But matrix.A will lead to memoryError if the matrix is very big.

Answer (score 14):

I've found that the advertised fast row indexing of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` can be made a lot quicker by rolling your own row indexer. Here's the idea:

```
class SparseRowIndexer:
    def __init__(self, csr_matrix):
        data = []
        indices = []
        indptr = []

        # Iterating over the rows this way is significantly more efficient
        # than csr_matrix[row_index,:] and csr_matrix.getrow(row_index)
        for row_start, row_end in zip(csr_matrix.indptr[:-1], csr_matrix.indptr[1:]):
             data.append(csr_matrix.data[row_start:row_end])
             indices.append(csr_matrix.indices[row_start:row_end])
             indptr.append(row_end-row_start) # nnz of the row

        self.data = np.array(data)
        self.indices = np.array(indices)
        self.indptr = np.array(indptr)
        self.n_columns = csr_matrix.shape[1]

    def __getitem__(self, row_selector):
        data = np.concatenate(self.data[row_selector])
        indices = np.concatenate(self.indices[row_selector])
        indptr = np.append(0, np.cumsum(self.indptr[row_selector]))

        shape = [indptr.shape[0]-1, self.n_columns]

        return sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=shape)
```

That is, it is possible to utilize the fast indexing of numpy arrays by storing the non-zero values of each row in separate arrays (with a different length for each row) and putting all of those row arrays in an object-typed array (allowing each row to have a different size) that can be indexed efficiently. The column indices are stored the same way. The approach is slightly different to the standard CSR data structure which stores all non-zero values in a single array, requiring look-ups to see where each row starts and ends. These look-ups can slow down random access but should be efficient for retrieval of contiguous rows.

### Profiling results

My matrix `mat` is a 1,900,000x1,250,000 `csr_matrix` with 400,000,000 non-zero elements.
`ilocs` is an array of 200,000 random row indices.

```
>>> %timeit mat[ilocs]
2.66 s ± 233 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

compared to:

```
>>> row_indexer = SparseRowIndexer(mat)
>>> %timeit row_indexer[ilocs]
59.9 ms ± 4.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The SparseRowIndexer seems to be faster when using fancy indexing compared to boolean masks.