# Fast slicing and multiplication of scipy sparse CSR matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse `CSR` matrix of size 2M x 50k with 200M non-zero values (100 per row). I need to slice 120k rows of it by a (randomly distributed) index (which is a pandas `Series`) and then multiply that submatrix by a sparse vector of size 1x50k (with 100 non-zero values as well).

I do this:

```
slice = matrix[index.tolist(), :]
result = slice.dot(vector.T).T.toarray()[0]  # returns 1x120k array
```

The slicing takes `0.7s` (slow) and then multiplication takes `0.05s`.

Instead, I can multiply the whole matrix first and then slice the result:

```
result = matrix.dot(vector.T).T.toarray()[0]
result_sliced = result[index.tolist()]  # returns 1x120k array
```

In this case, multiplication takes `0.65s` and then slicing takes `0.015s`.

Questions:

1. Why is slicing of a CSR matrix by rows so slow? Even multiplication of the whole matrix takes less time than it.
2. Is there a way to achieve the end result faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained in [Sparse matrix slicing using list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int) that this kind of row indexing is actually performed with matrix multiplication.  In effect it constructs a sparse vector with 1's for the desired rows, and does the appropriate `dot`.

So I'm not surprised that the order of the operations doesn't matter much.

In general sparse matrices are not designed for efficient indexing.  They don't, for example, return views.  The `csr` matrix multiplication is one its most efficient operations.  Even row or columns sums are performed with matrix multiplication.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the end result faster?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and my solution was to write a row extractor that relies on indexing of numpy arrays rather than sparse matrix multiplications. [See my approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843352/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-slice-a-scipy-sparse-matrix/50860352#50860352).

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough RAM memory you can convert tolil() and slicing should be faster.

Comment: Next time you can post this as a comment and not as an answer