# Cope with different slicing-behaviour in scipy.sparse and numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

***Setup***

I'm aware of the fact that sparse matrices in scipy's `.sparse`-module differ from `numpy`-arrays. Also, I'm aware of questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843352/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-slice-a-scipy-sparse-matrix) regarding slicing of sparse arrays. Anyhow, this and most other questions deal with the performance of slicing.

My question rather deals with how to cope with their different slicing-behaviour. Lets create an example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

matrix = np.asarray([[0,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1]])
sparse_matrix = sparse.lil_matrix(matrix) # Or another format like .csr_matrix etc.
```

Given this setup, applying the same slice results in a different output:

```py
matrix[:, 3]
# Output: 
# array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

sparse_matrix[:, 3]
# Output:
# matrix([[ True],
#        [False],
#        [False],
#        [ True],
#        [ True],
#        [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

***Question***

This is a bit of a bummer, since I need the first output to apply in the second case as well. As said in the beginning, I know that using `sparse_matrix.A` etc. will give me the desired result. Anyhow, converting the sparse matrix to an array contradicts with the initial use-case of sparse-matrices.

So is there some possibility to achieve the same slice-result without converting `sparse-matrix` to an array?

**Edit:**
For clarification, since my question might be confusing regarding this: The slice on the `sparse_matrix` shall have the same output as `matrix`, meaning that something like `sparse_matrix[:, 3]` shall output `([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True])`.

Comment: You can use `matrix[:, 3:4]` to get an output like that of `sparse_matrix[:, 3]`.

Comment: Sparse matrix is like `np.matrix`.  Indexing like this returns a matrix which is always 2d.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I updated my question to clarify this (sorry, it was confusing): The output of `sparse_matrix` shall have the same as `matrix`, not the other way around.

Comment: *"The slice on the `sparse_matrix` shall have the same output as `matrix`"*.  The problem is that `matrix` is a 2-d numpy array, so `matrix[:, 3]` is a *one-dimensional* array.  `sparse_matrix` is a sparse matrix object, and slicing a sparse matrix always returns another sparse matrix, and these objects are *always* two-dimensional.  You would have to do something like `sparse_matrix[:, 3].A.ravel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [150]: arr = np.asarray([[0,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1]]) 
     ...: M = sparse.lil_matrix(arr) # Or another format like .csr_matrix etc.
```

A scalar index on a `ndarray` reduces the dimensions by one:

```
In [151]: arr[:,3]                                                                                           
Out[151]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

It does not change the number of dimensions of the sparse matrix.

```
In [152]: M[:,3]                                                                                             
Out[152]: 
<6x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

This behavior is similar to that of `np.matrix` subclass (and MATLAB).  A sparse matrix is always 2d.

The dense array display of this matrix:

```
In [153]: M[:,3].A                                                                                           
Out[153]: 
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]], dtype=int64)
```

and the `np.matrix` display:

```
In [154]: M[:,3].todense()                                                                                   
Out[154]: 
matrix([[1],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]], dtype=int64)
```

`np.matrix` has a `A1` property which produces a 1d array (it converts to `ndarray` and applies `ravel`):

```
In [155]: M[:,3].todense().A1                                                                                
Out[155]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

`ravel`, `squeeze` and scalar indexing are all ways of reducing the dimensions of a `ndarray`.  But they don't work directly on a `np.matrix` or sparse matrix.

Another example of a 2d sparse matrix:

```
In [156]: sparse.lil_matrix(arr[:,3])                                                                        
Out[156]: 
<1x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [157]: _.A                                                                                                
Out[157]: array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Note the `[[...]]`.  `sparse` has added a leading size 1 dimension to the 1d `ndarray`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. A bit sad though that it's not directly possible to slice the sparse matrix as intended.

Comment: You might want to explore how the matrices are stored.   You `lil` is stored by row.  Selecting a row is fairly straight forward; there's even a 'view' like method.  But selecting a column means finding values across rows.  Similarly `csr` is optimized for row access, while its transpose gives columns more directly.